# SQLiteException thrown without message while db upgrade on a few Android devices

Tags: java, android, sqlite

An `SQLiteException` is thrown on a few devices while upgrading the database in production but unfortunately not reproducible for me (around 10% of the active devices are affected):

Table before upgrade:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "UPDATE_CHECK_ENTITY" (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,LICENSE_TOKEN TEXT,RELEASE_NOTE TEXT,VERSION TEXT,URL_TO_APK TEXT,URL_TO_RELEASE_NOTE TEXT);

INSERT INTO UPDATE_CHECK_ENTITY(LICENSE_TOKEN,URL_TO_APK,URL_TO_RELEASE_NOTE,_id,RELEASE_NOTE,VERSION) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

Upgrade script to add `APK_SHA256` to the table scheme:

```sql
ALTER TABLE "UPDATE_CHECK_ENTITY" RENAME TO "UPDATE_CHECK_ENTITY_OLD";

CREATE TABLE "UPDATE_CHECK_ENTITY" (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,LICENSE_TOKEN TEXT,RELEASE_NOTE TEXT,VERSION TEXT,URL_TO_APK TEXT,APK_SHA256 TEXT,URL_TO_RELEASE_NOTE TEXT);

INSERT INTO "UPDATE_CHECK_ENTITY" ("_id","LICENSE_TOKEN","RELEASE_NOTE","VERSION","URL_TO_APK","URL_TO_RELEASE_NOTE") SELECT "UPDATE_CHECK_ENTITY_OLD"."_id","UPDATE_CHECK_ENTITY_OLD"."LICENSE_TOKEN","UPDATE_CHECK_ENTITY_OLD"."RELEASE_NOTE","UPDATE_CHECK_ENTITY_OLD"."VERSION","UPDATE_CHECK_ENTITY_OLD"."URL_TO_APK","UPDATE_CHECK_ENTITY_OLD"."URL_TO_RELEASE_NOTE" FROM "UPDATE_CHECK_ENTITY_OLD";

DROP TABLE "UPDATE_CHECK_ENTITY_OLD";
```

The following exception occurs on a few devices but not reproducible for me:

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3654)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3806)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2267)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8167)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:496)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1100)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement (Native Method)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement (SQLiteConnection.java:1372)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare (SQLiteConnection.java:811)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare (SQLiteSession.java:590)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init> (SQLiteProgram.java:62)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init> (SQLiteStatement.java:33)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql (SQLiteDatabase.java:2329)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL (SQLiteDatabase.java:2257)
  at org.cryptomator.data.db.Sql$SqlInsertSelectBuilder.executeOn (Sql.java:293)
```

Creating the new `UPDATE_CHECK_ENTITY` table works, the exception is thrown while executing the `INSERT`. `UPDATE_CHECK_ENTITY_OLD` doesn't exists before.

Some users report that reinstalling the app fixes the problem but this database upgrade is then also performed so I have no reason what the problem could be :/.

If it helps, here's the part of the source code where it crashes but probably too much to dig into first
https://github.com/cryptomator/android/blob/ff2596689f134cf769f9253276a5955eae355b3d/data/src/main/java/org/cryptomator/data/db/Upgrade6To7.kt#L33-L37

Comment: Do you have any info about the Android API version of the affected devices?

Comment: @forpas until now it only happens only on API level 29 and 30 but I don't know whether we just don't have any crash reports from others yet or the problem can really be limited to that.